# iOS 8 Safari - Height Transition jerky

Tags: jquery, ios, css

I have an ul element which should expand on click. I use CSS transitions for that. On click Javascript assigns the "select_ul_open"-class. These are the relevant style attributes:

```
    .select_ul {
        height: 0px;
        visibility: hidden;
        transition: height .4s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0, 1.000), visibility 0s linear .4s;
    }

    .select_ul.select_ul_open {
        height: 320px;
        visibility: visible;
        transition: height .4s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0, 1.000), visibility .4s linear 0s;
    }
```

It works pretty good on all common desktop browsers. However it is jerky on iOS Mobile or on Android Browser. People told me to add

```
    tratranslate3d(0px,0px,0px)
```

to my code which activates hardware acceleration but that didn't work out for the height-transition.

I also tried to make it fadeIn with jQuery. The funny thing is that it worked fine for iOS but not for desktop browser like Chrome.

Is there any universal solution for this problem? And if not, is there any other way to make a smooth fade-in transition?

Cheers,
David

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you have this solved already, but here are a few things to try:

- add "overflow-y: hidden" to ".select_ul {"
- remove "visibility" entirely
- transition should only be established once, use it for ".select_ul {" and not ".select_ul_open"

So, your code should be:

```
.select_ul {
    height: 0px;
    transition: height .4s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0, 1.000);
}
.select_ul.select_ul_open {
    height: 320px;
}
```

If that still doesn't work, try replacing the transition timing-function with "linear":

```
.select_ul {
    height: 0px;
    transition: height .4s linear;
}
.select_ul.select_ul_open {
    height: 320px;
}
```

Also, I'm sure this was just a stackexchange typo, but its worth pointing out:

```
tratranslate3d(0px,0px,0px)
```

should be:

```
transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px);
```

...but that really shouldn't be needed anyways. Hopefully that helps. Cheers!